# Post ID is listed twice in SO permalinks

Tags: support, hyperlinks, permalink, post-id

Why is the post ID duplicated in permalinks on SO (or any other Stack Exchange site)?

For instance:

> http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/**1732454#1732454**

Why have the extra digits when this would be enough?

> http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not enough. See

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#3180176)

versus

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/3180176#3180176)

Comment: This depends a bit on the sort order. Be sure to sort on votes, or log out of SO, before clicking the above.

Comment: As of now, those links doesn't seem to make any difference anymore.