# 76 Unclosed Questions on SO Tagged [stackoverflow.com]

Tags: discussion, questions

I was surprised to do the following search

```
[stackoverflow.com] closed:0
```

and see 76 questions. Perhaps these should be mass-migrated to meta?

BTW, I did the search because of seeing [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79861/duplicated-comment-id-in-so-permalinks) question.

Comment: @Bill The Lizard: What should we do with these questions?  Most of them are meta questions, but I don't want to flood meta with old, unwanted questions.

Comment: I'm suggesting we migrate them, then let the meta community deal with closing, editing, etc.

Comment: @Robert: If it would be a duplicate we can just close it on SO and link to the original here on Meta.  That should be most of them.  Some are actual programming questions, like [How to implement a reputation system like Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735168/how-to-implement-a-reputation-system-like-stack-overflow), and can just stay put.

Comment: @John: You can help by picking a few, determining if they are duplicates, and migrating or closing as appropriate.

Comment: @Robert: ahah, you want me to actually _do_ something instead of merely suggesting that someone _else_ do something. I'll have to do some thinking on that...

Comment: +1: I gave you ten magical meta credits for your trouble. :)

Comment: @Robert: It might be easier to do it John's way.  If we migrate them first, it will be easier to close as duplicate, rather than manually editing them to link to the original.

Comment: @Robert: I feel ten points more blessed.

Comment: A ton of these really are programming questions asking how to do things similar to what you see on SO.  I'm going to migrate some that do belong on Meta, but I'm not sure what to do about the `stackoverflow.com` tag.  Should we get rid of it?

Comment: @Bill: I would get rid of that tag. Considering the age of many of those questions, a more appropriate tag might be "like-stackexchange".

Comment: @Bill: I concur with getting rid of it.  It's a recursive meta tag. :)

Comment: @Robert: Now I like it *more*.  :)